# Removing accents in column names in R

Tags: r

I have tried almost every solution in this website so I am starting to think that this may be an issue coming from the excel files. Anyways I have multiple xlsx files with sheets that I have merged into one dataframe (using map_df). Unfortuntely, the names are in spanish and it creates issues with R as the code progresses. The accented names are only in the column names, any tips or recommendations as to how to tackle this when it comes to just the accent names? Not sure if it coming from xlsx files is the reason why the codes I have tried don't work. Thank you.

dput data sample as requested:

```
structure(list(file = c("location1/location2/namelocationfile1.xlsx", 
"location1/location2/namelocationfile2.xlsx", 
"location1/location2/namelocationfile3.xlsx", 
"location1/location2/namelocationfile4.xlsx", 
"location1/location2/namelocationfile5.xlsx", 
"location1/location2/namelocationfile6.xlsx"
), sheet = c("TOTAL-2015 ", "TOTAL-2015 ", "TOTAL-2015 ", "TOTAL-2015 ", 
"TOTAL-2015 ", "TOTAL-2015 "), age = c("Total", "0-4", "0", 
"1", "2", "3"), total = c("355461", "35173", "7091", "7042", 
"7027", "7008"), plán = c("126131", "11698", "2407", "2318", 
"2349", "2282"), pláns = c("8456", "726", "162", "135", "133", 
"138"), place = c("35112", "2969", "599", "607", "555", 
"597"), concepción = c("12912", "1283", "281", "263", 
"244", "253"), refugio = c("10959", "903", "174", "174", "206", 
"184"), lugar = c("20733", "2229", "431", "454", "409", "486"
), san_marco = c("31082", "3271", "624", "658", "670", "656"), 
    menéndez = c("47495", "5070", "990", "1023", 
    "1008", "1020"), san = c("10244", "955", "193", "203", 
    "189", "194"), san_pedro = c("8374", "915", "183", 
    "181", "205", "175"), buenosaires = c("33242", "4244", "862", 
    "857", "894", "836"), turín = c("10721", "910", "185", "169", 
    "165", "187")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: If all your files share the same column names, it may be a good solution to provide a `col_names` vector to `read_excel`.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far and provide reproducible data in the form of a few lines of the data (`dput(head(Data))`) once you have imported it into R.

Comment: @Mako212 what you are saying is to name them individually using col_names? If so yes that is the best and easiest option but unfortunately it is at least 100 or so and my main goal is to make this script as open as possible so it can be used with other data.

Comment: @dcarlson i placed a data sample. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one possible solution with `iconv`:

```
string <- c("à", "è", "ì"," ò"," ù", "À", "È", "Ì", "Ò", "Ù")

# [1] "à"  "è"  "ì"  " ò" " ù" "À"  "È"  "Ì"  "Ò"  "Ù" 


gsub("`", "", iconv(string, from = "UTF-8", , to='ASCII//TRANSLIT'))

# [1] "a"  "e"  "i"  " o" " u" "A"  "E"  "I"  "O"  "U"
```

Another option with `stringi` that doesn't require `gsub`:

```
library(stringi)
stri_trans_general(str = string, id = "Latin-ASCII")

# [1] "a"  "e"  "i"  " o" " u" "A"  "E"  "I"  "O"  "U"
```

**Update**

To apply function to the column names with `rename_with`, we need to use `.x` in `iconv`. Additionally, for `gsub`, the pattern is `'` instead of "`".

```
library(tidyverse)

df_new <- df %>% 
    rename_with(., ~ gsub("'", "", iconv(.x, from = "UTF-8", to='ASCII//TRANSLIT')))

# Or we can use `stringr` instead of `gsub`:
# df %>% 
#    rename_with(., ~ str_replace_all(iconv(.x, to='ASCII//TRANSLIT'), "'", ""))

colnames(df_new)
# [1] "file"        "sheet"       "age"         "total"       "plan"        "plans"       "place"       "concepcion"  "refugio"    
# [10] "lugar"       "san_marco"   "menendez"    "san"         "san_pedro"   "buenosaires" "turin"
```

base R options:

```
colnames(df) <- gsub("'", "", iconv(colnames(df), from = "UTF-8", to='ASCII//TRANSLIT'))
```

Or:

```
colnames(df) <- stri_trans_general(str = colnames(df), id = "Latin-ASCII")
```

Comment: why do you have `gsub`?

Comment: I have been using `gsub` with `rename_with` to clean other parts of the columns. I tried the following ``rename_with(~ gsub("`", "", iconv(string, to='ASCII//TRANSLIT'),.x)) `` and got this error `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthError: Names must be unique.
x These names are duplicated:
  * "a" at locations 1 and 11.
  * "e" at locations 2 and 12.
  * etc.....`

Comment: @Onyambu With accented characters, it will return `[1] "`a"  "`e"  "`i"  " `o" " `u" "`A"  "`E"  "`I"  "`O"  "`U" `, so I have to remove the ```. I also just added a `stringi` option that doesn't require `gsub`.

Comment: @BoniPhila If you edit your question, and paste the results of `dput()` on your dataframe, then I can check and see what the issue is. You can also wrap it in `head` to just give a minimum example.

Comment: @AndrewGillreath-Brown Thank you, I changed some names around but basically it's just the column names that need to get rid of the accents. Some have them others don't. I posted it on the original.

Comment: @BoniPhila I've updated my answer to include those other options. Essentially, the only problem with your `rename_with` statement is that you had `string` in the `iconv` function, but you need to have `.x`, so that each column name passes through the function.

Comment: @AndrewGillreath-Brown the line works, thank you for that but the conversion does not work properly. For example: out of the column names. chapán `chapA!n` and concepción resulted in concepciA3n. Is there other options other than ASCII//TRANSLIT? I assume that's the issue?

Comment: @BoniPhila That sounds like you may have different encoding from the xlsx than with me getting the `dput()` from above, as I don't get that issue at all. You could try a different `from` parameter for `iconv`. Just lookup `?iconv` to see the options. I was assuming that you had an `UTF-8`. If you are on Windows, then you could try `from = "CP1252"` or `latin1`.  Also, did you get the same issue with using `stri_trans_general` or just with `iconv`?

Comment: @AndrewGillreath-Brown thank you!!! from = 'UTF-8' worked! It now works properly thank you so much, I can't believe this was so complicated but in the end it was that!