# Remove special characters (Spanish characters) from strings in shiny server

Tags: r, character-encoding

I currently have a table of names with Spanish characters and I used the following process to fix those characters:

```
data <- tibble(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  original.name = c("Juan Carlos Mondrag<f3>n Consuelo","Rub<e9>n Salgado Ceballos",
                    "Mois<e9>s Alc<e1>ntara lujan","Luis Garc<ed>a Escobar",
                    "Gilberto Perez Casta<f1>eda")
)

data$original.name <- iconv(data$original.name, "latin1", "latin1")
```

That works fine when I run the code locally but when I want to apply that to a simple shiny app when uploading it to the cloud it doesn't work the same; in those cases it returns the following characters:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this in the shinyapps server? I tried using "UTF-8" but it doesn't works.

**Note: this basically happens with accents and the letter "ñ"**

Comment: What you pasted here does not have accepts, it has the literal (e.g.) `g`, `<` , `f`, `3`, `>`, `n`, etc. Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/q/71179702/3358272?